# Which NPCs have the lowest magic skills across the games?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-series

Like how *Oblivion* have [Merchants with only 5 Mercantile skill](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Merchants#Base_Game), who's the character with the worst magic skill(s)?

If there's ties, like "This guy has 0 Destruction, but this girl has 0 Restoration", I want to know all those ties.